# What alternatives to Booking.com/Airbnb currently work in Russia?

Tags: online-resources, russia

I'm looking to book an apartment in Moscow for 2 weeks this summer. What alternatives exist for Booking.com/Airbnb, which shut down their operations in Russia last year? Ideally it would be a platform that lets me put down a reservation using a Visa/Mastercard but Mir could also work as a worst case scenario.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145986/discussion-on-question-by-jonathanreez-what-alternatives-to-booking-com-airbnb-c); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed. And if more comment that do not ask for clarification are posted the comments get locked.

Answer (score 15):

There are two obvious alternatives:

- [Ostrovok.ru](https://ostrovok.ru/), which is a decade old faithful clone of Booking.com with somewhat better UI, I've used it half an hour ago to book a hotel in Vytegra. Many hotels do not require paying in advance at all — you may pay in cash when you arrive.
- [sutochno.ru](https://sutochno.ru/), which is more like AirBNB, but mostly targets business travellers and not party goers. Expect short term flat rentals. It would usually be sufficient to prepay a fraction of stay via Sberbank/SBP instant transfer. Most apartment rentals cannot accept cards anyway.

There are perhaps other options, e.g., try [Aeroflot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroflot) or [RZD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Railways) who will try to upsell a hotel to you.

Comment: Have you tried onetwotrip? they claim to support different payment systems depending on locale I didn't test though(I used them in EU and Russia but not recently)

Comment: I've certainly used onetwotrip but only with airplane tickets. I'm not sure what are their hotel options or how good they are. It's quite possible that it's robust and catered to international audience, but I just lack data.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest trying [Avito](https://www.avito.ru) for renting an apartment short-term. As a replacement of AirBnB.

[Avito](https://www.avito.ru) is a general classified advertisement service, so you have to switch to the [real estate section](https://www.avito.ru/moskva/nedvizhimost). Unfortunately, the service does not have an English language version of the website, but online translation service do a decent job translating it on the fly.